# Frequency Scaling Monitor for Windows

Tags: windows-7, power-management, performance-monitor

What program is there to monitor the current CPU frequency (not the nominal CPU speed) on a Windows 7 system, similar to the [Frequency Scaling Monitor](http://library.gnome.org/users/cpufreq-applet/2.32/cpufreq-applet.html) applet in GNOME?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPU frequency can be seen in the [Resource Monitor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-Resource-Monitor), see the blue line here:

[image]